# Hadoop Development Tool Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

http://hdt.incubator.apache.org/install.html

Download the zipped update site(Binary) and add the location of the archive. The plugin will be shown after select 'Only local sites'.

The plugin is not shown after this.

Please check it.

Giving below error:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=epp.package.java,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.apache.hdt.core,0.0.2.incubating No repository found
>   containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.apache.hdt.feature,0.0.2.incubating No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.apache.hdt.hadoop.release,0.0.2.incubating No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.apache.hdt.hadoop2.release,0.0.2.incubating No
>   repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.apache.hdt.ui,0.0.2.incubating

Answer (score 0):

At the dialog box where it asks for Name and Location rather than using the `Archive` Button simply copy paste the path to the extracted hdt folder.

Something like this

```
Name: Apache Hadoop Development Tools
Location: /path/to/extracted/folder/hdt-0.0.1.incubating-bin
```